# Setting up CUDA

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have a Lenovo Y580, and I am following the instructions from [this blog post](http://chrislaidler.blogspot.ca/2012/12/getting-nvidia-optimus-working-on-my.html) to set up my laptop for gpu programming. At the end of the blog post, he says

> You will have to install gcc 4.4
>
> $ sudo apt-get install -y gcc-4.4 g++-4.4
>
> $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.4 /usr/local/cuda/bin/gcc
>
> And tell nvcc to use it with the directive: --compiler-bindir=/usr/local/cuda/bin

What does it mean to "tell nvcc to use it with the directive: --compiler-bindir=/usr/local/cuda/bin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**nvcc** stands for  **NVIDIA's CUDA C/C++ compiler toolchain**.

the blog is telling you should compile with this flag:

> --compiler-bindir=/usr/local/cuda/bin